# @DiscriminatorFormula - redundant IN restriction

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have hierarchy of classes, for example AbstractClass - Employee - Engineer (and many others subclasses), and I use single table per class hierarchy strategy.
AbstractClass has property `case`, in Employee I define `@DiscriminatorFormula("case")`, Engineer has some `@DiscriminatorValue`.

When I load all objects with HQL-query `SELECT id FROM Employee`, Hibernate makes this SQL-query:

`select employee0_.id as col_0_0_ from public.tbl_employee employee0_ where employee0_.case in ('engineer', 'operator')`

In other words, Hibernate adds redundant restrictoin with all discriminator values.

Is there a way to exclude this IN restriction from SQL?

---

There is some simplified mapping of AbstractClass and Employee:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "objectid_sequence", allocationSize = 100)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "case", nullable = false)
    private String case;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_employee")
@DiscriminatorFormula("case")
public class Employee extends AbstractClass {

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name = "";
}
```

Comment: i do not know if the restriction can be excluded but the reason behind it is that there might be other subclasses of Abstract class with different descriminator values which must be excluded

Comment: Yes, there are another subclasses of Abstract. But Abstract has annotation @MappedSuperclass. And only Employee sublcasses store in TBL_EMPLOYEE.
Looks like Hibernate doesn't know it.